# How to load base64 of PDF file to jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf

I am using jsPDF in the backend and I am trying to add a text to an existing PDF which is in base64.

The code I am working on is basic as of now

```
const {jsPDF} = require('jspdf')

const pdfDoc = new jsPDF();
const base64PDF = "{{Base64 of PDF file}}"
pdfDoc.addImage(base64PDF, 'PDF', 0, 0, 210, 297);
pdfDoc.setFontSize(20);
pdfDoc.text("Hello World", 100, 100);
const modifiedPDFContent = pdfDoc.output('datauristring');
const modifiedPDFData = modifiedPDFContent.split(',')[1];
fs.writeFileSync("abc.pdf", modifiedPDFData, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

I am trying to add the text to the first page of the existing pdf which is in base64 format. But unable to load that PDF into jsPDF.

Comment: addImage doesn't accept PDF as filetype